# Discrete superharmonicity

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, graph-theory, harmonic-analysis, operator-theory

The value at $(n,m)$ of the “Discrete Laplace operator” (see wikipedia) of a function $f$ in $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$ is $\Delta f(n,m)=  \frac{1}{4}( f(n+1,m)+f(n,m+1)+f(n-1,m)+f(n,m-1))-f(n,m)$:

the difference between the average of $f$ at the $4$ next points and the value of f at $(n,m)$.

If $g\in C^2(\Bbb R^2)$ we can set
$f_\varepsilon (n,m)=g(x+n\varepsilon,y+n\varepsilon)$, then when $\varepsilon\downarrow 0$, $ f_\varepsilon\to g$ and  $\Delta f_\varepsilon\to\Delta g$ the usual Laplacian. Usual harmonic ($\Delta g=0$) and subharmonic
($\Delta g\geq 0$) functions in $g\in C^2(\Bbb R^2)$  when upper-bounded are constant.

> **Question 1** Upper-bounded discrete harmonic functions $f$ in $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$ are constant? (I have done that)
>
> **Question 2** Is that still true for discrete sub-harmonics? (I could not do that but might be in some paper).

Judgments about the banality of the questions are welcome if preceded by their solutions or references.

Comment: For the benefit of other readers: I would like to suggest that those who have voted to close have mistaken this question for an exercise, when the text indicates that it is actually a genuine question arising from an easier version that the OP could solve

Comment: I will elaborate a more pompous version. This is a difficult problem in discrete harmonic analysis. It might be treated in some paper. Even the harmonic case (which I solved) is absolutely nontrivial. People should solve problems before snubbing them.

Comment: @ClaudioRea I voted to close your question; I voted to reopen it. Closing a question doesn't mean snubbing it. It's often done on the belief that the question is an exercise, according to a number of clues (a sketch of proof in the mind, also "I can't do it" in the title which is often evidence for poor level questions, etc.). Such cooperative closing maintains the quality of the site. It happens to accidentally close questions which shouldn't be. The best reaction one can do in such cases (and you did) is to edit the question with additional information/context or improve it.

Comment: Regarding problem 1, [Deny, *Sur l’équation de convolution* $\mu = \mu * \sigma$](http://www.numdam.org/article/SBCD_1959-1960__4__A5_0.pdf) is a classical reference, I think.

Comment: @SamHopkins: Isn't this paper about *signed* super-harmonic functions?

Comment: Problem 2 seems to follow by general theory, although I did not verify the assumptions for the Riesz decomposition theorem. This theorem asserts that every positive super-harmonic function decomposes into the sum of a positive harmonic function and a potential. We already know that harmonic functions are zero everywhere, and in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ the potential is either everywhere zero or everywhere infinite.

Comment: If somebody is interested in, I can show my hand-made solution of problem 1

Comment: I think there is a discrepancy between the question in the title and the in the body of the question: one is about superharmonic functions (nonnegative, I guess), the other one is about bounded subharmonic functions. Anyway, in both cases one can use the random walk: if you apply your function to the random walk then you get a nonnegative supermartingale (or bounded submartingale); by martingale convergence theorem it converges. But the random walk is recurrent, so the function has to be constant.

Comment: I changed super-harmonicity into sub-harmonicity just for having a reference in wiki. I really believe that the reader understands that the only difference is the sign. Frankly this seems to me a very minor discrepancy. Mateusz's arguments are much beyond my culture, I don't doubt that they are very solid. My poor answer to question 1, that I wouldn't dare to publish on M.O., is really down to earth but has the advantage being self-contained and tactile, accessible to everybody. That's probably the reason why I could not extend it to question 2.